# MIUI heads up notification not working

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, heads-up-notifications, miui

I'm struggling to get my notifications to display heads up or peek as it is also called.

It is working fine with stock Android and Lineage OS API 21-26

What needs to be done to get it to work in MIUI 8?

The app has ALL notification permissions allowed.

This is an example of my notification code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "service_notifications")
        .setContentTitle(name)
        .setContentText("\uD83D\uDD14" + res.getText(R.string.imminent_arrival_text) + String.valueOf(Long.parseLong(eta) / 60) + res.getText(R.string.minutes_at_text) + simpleETA)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
        .setContentIntent(null)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_dialog_close_light, res.getText(R.string.stop_following_label), closePendingIntent)                                
        .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.quite_impressed))
        .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000})                                    
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)                                    
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE);

    notificationManager.notify(
        Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
        notification.build());
}
```

Comment: did you try adding a vibration pattern?

Comment: Hi yes I have. I've added an example of the code above. That code generates a heads-up on Stock android and LineageOS but not on MIUI... And yes, all the notification permissions have been given to the app.

Comment: Try adding setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)

Comment: i have added the solution for MIUi please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in two ways.

Go to:

1. Settings
2. Installed apps (migrate to your app)
3. Select your app and go to notifications ( **toggle on Priority and also toggle on Floating notification** )

Or, create a remote view(your own layout in **res/layout** ) and set `customHeadsUpNotification`

```
 RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notif_custom_view);

 notification_builder.createHeadsUpContentView(remoteViews);
```

Don't forget to change the notification_id after doing these changes.

Comment: Thanks! For the first time I'm able to trigger heads up on MIUI. I'll see if it makes sense now to rebuild all of my Notifications to use RemoveViews instead.

Comment: `createHeadsUpContentView(remoteViews)` doesn't take remoteViews as arg. Also it is not working for me on miui 10. Can you help @santanu-sur